# After upgrading to Neo4j 3.2 query by node label returns nothing

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I just downloaded Neo4J 3.2 and moved my database from 3.1 to 3.2. I'm on a Linux machine. The logs/neo4j.log file says that the  database was successfully upgraded. All of my nodes seem to be in the database with their appropriate labels. Querying on paths works fine. However, I can't query on label.

This returns the correct nodes with the correct labels:

`MATCH p=()-[r:Public_Funding]->() RETURN p LIMIT 25`

These return nothing:

```
MATCH p=(:City_Contracts)-[r:Public_Funding]->() RETURN p LIMIT 25
MATCH p=(:State_Contracts)-[r:Public_Funding]->() RETURN p LIMIT 25
MATCH (n:City_Spending) RETURN n
```

Nodes with the labels `:City_Spending`, `:City_Contracts` and `:State_Contracts` definitely exist, and appear when queried as part of a path.

What did I do to break my labels?

Comment: Are you viewing the results in Neo4j Browser? If true, please, can you edit your question and put a print screen of the result?

Comment: Query for labels like this: MATCH (n) RETURN labels(n). Or from the browser, look at the first item of the left side menu and check for the existence of the labels.

Comment: You may have to rebuild the label indexes.